# how to remove only ip from a txt file

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I have two files, one is `ips.yaml`:

```
-
  dedicatedip: 1.1.1.11
-
  dedicatedip: 2.2.2.2
-
  dedicatedip: ''
-
  dedicatedip: 3.3.3.3
-
  dedicatedip: 3.3.3.33
```

And this is my `result.txt`:

```
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| id       | hostname              | some other field | status | networks                    | plan          |
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| 11111111 | some-hostname         | some-value       | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.11  | not important |
| 11111111 | some another hostname |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.111 | not important |
| 11111111 | some.fqdn.com         |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.112 | not important |
| 11111111 | fourth.hostname.com   |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.1   | not important |
| 11111111 | the-other.com         | IHaveSomething   | Active | External_Networks=2.2.2.2   | not important |
| 11111111 | not.least.com         |                  | Active | External_Networks=2.2.2.25  | not important |
| 11111111 | last.fqdn.com         | The Last Value   | Active | External_Networks=3.3.3.39  | not important |
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
```

I want to remove each ips existed in `ips.yaml` from `result.txt`, so that the expected output would be:

```
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| id       | hostname              | some other field | status | networks                    | plan          |
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| 11111111 | some another hostname |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.111 | not important |
| 11111111 | some.fqdn.com         |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.112 | not important |
| 11111111 | fourth.hostname.com   |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.1   | not important |
| 11111111 | not.least.com         |                  | Active | External_Networks=2.2.2.25  | not important |
| 11111111 | last.fqdn.com         | The Last Value   | Active | External_Networks=3.3.3.39  | not important |
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
```

This is my current bash:

```
while read -r yaml_ips
do
    while read -r result_ips
    do
        if [ "$yaml_ips" == "$result_ips" ]
        then
            sed "/$yaml_ips/d" result.txt
        fi
    done < <(grep -Eo 'External_Networks=[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' result.txt | awk -F '=' '{print $2}')
done < <(awk '/dedicatedip: [0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}/ {print $2}' ips.yaml)
```

This is my current output:

```
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| id       | hostname              | some other field | status | networks                    | plan          |
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| id       | hostname              | some other field | status | networks                    | plan          |
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| 11111111 | some-hostname         | some-value       | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.11  | not important |
| 11111111 | some another hostname |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.111 | not important |
| 11111111 | some.fqdn.com         |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.112 | not important |
| 11111111 | fourth.hostname.com   |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.1   | not important |
| 11111111 | last.fqdn.com         | The Last Value   | Active | External_Networks=3.3.3.39  | not important |
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Regarding the data you marked as "not important" - yes, it is. It'd be very easy to come up with a solution that fails for certain values in that field, or to come up with a better answer depending on what that field might contain. I couldn't write the answer I initially intended to because I don't know what those "not important" values might be. Never assume anything is not important when asking a question since you don't know what the answer could be - provide truly representative examples of all data values.

Comment: I'm certain you've been referred to this before now but you have nested loops in your script so, please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @EdMorton thanks a lot for the comments. Regarding `not-important` field, I just wanted to say that the `networks` isn't the `$NF` or the last field. Also all plan names have two parts `A B` and that's why I added a space. Yes you're right. I could have written a plan name for all of them just to indicate last field isn't `networks`.

Comment: It was already clear that `networks` isn't the `$NF`, that's not the issue. My point is that different solutions are possible depending on what the contents of the `plan` field looks like. You're telling us now that it contains 2 space-separated strings - we couldn't have guessed that from `not important` in every field whereas if you had stated that in your question and provided representative values for them that would have been useful, would have led to different solutions being suggested, and so is important.

Comment: @EdMorton yes sir, they were my wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples only, please try following GNU `awk` code.

```
awk '
FNR==NR && /^ +/{
  ips[$2]
  next
}
(match($0,/External_Networks=(\S+)/,arr) && (arr[1] in ips)){
  next
}
(/^+-/) || (/^\|/){
  print
  next
} ' FS=": " ips.yaml result.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                              ##starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR && /^ +/{                  ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when ips.yaml file is being read and checking condition if a line starts with 1 or more spaces then do following.
  ips[$2]                          ##Creating array ips with index of $2 here.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
(match($0,/External_Networks=(\S+)/,arr) && (arr[1] in ips)){ ##Using match function to match External_Networks= followed by all 1 or more non-spaces and storing IPs values into array arr.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
(/^+-/) || (/^\|/){                ##Checking condition if line starts from +- OR | then do following.
  print                            ##Print that line.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
} ' FS=": " ips.yaml result.txt   ##Setting FS to colon space for file ips.yaml and then mentioning result.txt files.
```

Answer (score 2):

This 2 pass `awk` can do this in a single command:

```bash
awk -F ': ' '
FNR == NR {
   if (NF > 1 && $2 ~ /^[0-9]/)
      ips[$2]
   next
}
FNR > 3 {
   nw = $6
   sub(/^[^=]*=/, "", nw)
   if (nw in ips)
      next
}
1' ips.yaml FS='[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*' result.txt

i+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| id       | hostname              | some other field | status | networks                    | plan          |
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| 11111111 | some another hostname |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.111 | not important |
| 11111111 | some.fqdn.com         |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.112 | not important |
| 11111111 | fourth.hostname.com   |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.1   | not important |
| 11111111 | not.least.com         |                  | Active | External_Networks=2.2.2.25  | not important |
| 11111111 | last.fqdn.com         | The Last Value   | Active | External_Networks=3.3.3.39  | not important |
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
```

Here:

- `-F ': '` sets field separator as `": "` for the first file i.e. `ips.yaml`
- `FS='[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*'` sets field separator as `|` surrounded with whitespaces on either side for the 2nd file i.e. `result.txt`
- `NF > 1 && $2 ~ /^[0-9]/`: filters actual `ip` address lines in the 1st file and `ips[$2]` stores each ip address in associative array `ips`
- `FNR > 3` processed 2nd filed starting from 4th row, leaving first 3 header rows
- `sub(/^[^=]*=/, "", nw)` removes text before `=` and `=` from `networks` column i.e. `$6` in 2nd file

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { if ($1 == "dedicatedip:") ips[$2]; next }
    { o=$0; f=sub(/.*External_Networks=/,""); ip=$1; $0=o }
    !( f && (ip in ips) )
' ips.yaml result.txt
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| id       | hostname              | some other field | status | networks                    | plan          |
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
| 11111111 | some another hostname |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.111 | not important |
| 11111111 | some.fqdn.com         |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.112 | not important |
| 11111111 | fourth.hostname.com   |                  | Active | External_Networks=1.1.1.1   | not important |
| 11111111 | not.least.com         |                  | Active | External_Networks=2.2.2.25  | not important |
| 11111111 | last.fqdn.com         | The Last Value   | Active | External_Networks=3.3.3.39  | not important |
+----------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Very nice, avoids 2 FS patterns